# this.context returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-redux, react-dom

I'm setting up ContextApi for the first time in a production app, hoping to replace our current handling of our app configs with it. I've followed the official docs and consulted with similar issues other people are experiencing with the API, and gotten it to a point where I am able to correctly the config when I do Config.Consumer and a callback in render functions. However, I cannot get this.context to return anything other than an empty object.

Ideally, I would use this.context in lifecycle methods and to avoid callback hell, so help would be appreciated. I've double checked my React version and that I'm setting the contextType. Below is a representation of the code

config.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export default createContext();
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Router, browserHistory } from "react-router";
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from "react-router-redux";
import Config from "../somePath/config";
// more imports


function init() {
  const config = getConfig();
  const routes = getRoutes(config);
  const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, appStore);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={appStore}>
      <Config.Provider value={config}>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
      </Config.Provider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  );
}
init();
```

someNestedComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Config from "../somePath/config";

@connect(
  state => ({
    someState: state.someState,
  })
)
class someNestedComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context);
  }

  render() {
    return (...someJSX);
  }
}
someNestedComponent.contextType = Config;

export default someNestedComponent;
```

Currently running on:

- React 16.8.6 (hopi to see error messages about circuitous code but
  didn't get any warnings)
- React-DOM 16.7.0
- React-Redux 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `someNestedComponent` doesn't refer to the class where `this.context` is used:

```
someNestedComponent.contextType = Config;
```

It refers to functional component that wraps original class because it was decorated with `@connect` decorator, it is syntactic sugar for:

```
const someNestedComponent = connect(...)(class someNestedComponent extends Component {
  ...    
});
someNestedComponent.contextType = Config;
```

Instead, it should be:

```
@connect(...)
class someNestedComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = Config;

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context);
  }
  ...
}
```

There are no callback hell problems with context API; this is conveniently solved with same higher-order component pattern as used in React Redux and can also benefit from decorator syntax:

```
const withConfig = Comp => props => (
  <Config.Consumer>{config => <Comp config={config} {...props} />}</Config.Consumer>
);
@connect(...)
@withConfig
class someNestedComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.config);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This was a great answer - gave me the option to discuss with my team which approach we preferred, and ended up using public class syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use a `consumer` to get the values

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer